# How to run a different version of the iOS simulator on Xcode 11?

Tags: ios, device

I am currently working on iOS. My problem is that I set the Xcode to be updated automatically, so the Xcode was recently updated to 11. And the iOS version became 13. I need to be able to test the iPhone SE. But it doesn't seem to support the iOS 13 version. How can I test the iPhone SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to go to Xcode Preferences and then open Components tab. There you can download iOS simulators you need (probably iOS 12 Simulator to start with).

Answer (score 1):

`Xcode -> Preference -> Components` , then download the version and device you want to use.